# Bash script not deleting files in given directory

Tags: linux, bash, cron, find

I found this bash script online that I want to use to delete files older than 2 days:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

I setup a cronjob to run the script (I set it a couple of minutes ahead for testing, but it should run once every 24 hours)

```
54 18 * * * /path/to/another/dir/script.sh
```

I exit correct so it updates the cronjob.

Why does it not delete the files in the directory?

Comment: redirect the output to a file to get any error messages that might occur `54 18 * * * /path/to/another/dir/script.sh &>> /tmp/cronlog`

Comment: also note that `find` has a `-delete` option.

Comment: Well I ran the command on its own and it works, so it is just something wrong with the cronjob!?

Comment: Add a line such as `date >> /tmp/log` to your script just to make sure it is being run. Also check that your script is executable and that it is run by the correct user.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try dumping an echo at the end of the script and log the output

```
cron1.sh >> /var/log/cron1.log
```

You could try this but I'm not sure it will work

```
--exec rm -rf {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most cron jobs do not have PATH set. You must fully qualify the find command.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

If you capture the stdout and stderr as recommended by damienfrancois, you'd probably see the message "command not found: find". If you didn't capture the stdout and stderr, cron usually will send the output to the cron job owner's email, unless configured not to do so.

Comment: The param to -exec should also be fully qualified /bin/rm. Alternatively, set PATH in the script.